# Sending an input String to another form in c#

Tags: c#, forms

So I have one form:

[image: where the user will input a string]

I want to then turn that into a variable on form 2 that is printed on for Form 1 code I have

```cs
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            //have user type term to search, and bring that input to form2
            Form1.Enable = false;
            Form newForm = new Form2(textBox1);  //send data to new form
            newForm.ShowDialog();
```

thats on the button click where i assume that where it sends the data
but for the text box itself i have :

```cs
        private void txtBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form newForm = new Form2(textBox1);  //send data to new form
        }
```

for form 2 idk how to put it in the other text box as the string I am extremely new to c# as i am coming from python but here is my form 2 code:

```cs
        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Form2.Text = textBox1;
        }
```

note I have this in form 2 : `public Form2(string textBox1)`
and I want it to display in here:

[image]

note I am new so please be kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wonky here, you say you have modified the Form2 constructor to accept a string but then you seem to send a textbox into it instead:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        ...
        Form newForm = new Form2(textBox1);  //send data to new form
```

I would make this:

```
        Form2 newForm = new Form2(textBox1.Text);  //send data to new form
```

And then make your Form2's constructor set the text in the form2 textbox:

```
    public Form2(string tx){ //you must have this already
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        someOtherTextboxOnForm2.Text = tx; //do it after InitializeComponent call
```

---

Please call your controls something different than "Form2", "textbox1" - youre allowed to rename them, it takes seconds to do and your code won't degenerate into an incomprehensible mess after about 10 controls